# Is it possible to use variables across multiple iterations of a survey?

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

For Qualtrics (surveys / research core) I am wondering if it is possible to show results from surveys recorded so far at the end of the survey.

Highly simplified example: Let's say I have a question asking people about their favorite ice cream flavor, with a few answer options. I have already recorded the responses of 300 people, and the most chosen flavor is chocolate. Then when someone new takes the survey survey, after they answer 'vanilla' for that question, I want show something like: "Your favorite flavor is vanilla. Most people like chocolate." I know how to use custom javascript and embedded variables, but the variables always stay within the 'bounds' of the single survey that someone is taking.

Is it possible to record and do operations on variables across multiple iterations of the same survey?

Comment: To do something like this requires persistent storage on the server. I.e a database of some kind. Edit because I see you mentioned Qualtrics: they are storing the results of the surveys, so I'd assume they provide some type of API or other hook you can use to retrieve and process previous survey results from your javascript. I haven't used their software before though, so I can't help much.

Answer (score 1):

You could create quotas for each of the variables to track. Then use branch logic to display the appropriate text based on which one has a higher value.